# How to return/simulate error 102 from nginx?

Tags: webserver, hosts, nginx

Is it possible to return for a specific domain an error, like if the server (nginx) would not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, here is an example of returning a 102 status code when browsing to the root of the virtual host:

```
location / {
    try_files =102
}
```

However, 102 is not a valid HTTP status code. You should select a more appropriate status code to indicate that the server is not working, such as 501.

Comment: try_files doesn't work for me, still 404. 501 works, but still is visible that it is an answer of nginx.

Comment: You want to look at the `server_tokens` directive. You can use that to disable all the nginx branding.

Comment: server_tokens - only on/off. nginx brand still there. I want do not server one subdomain, like the nginx would be off, not just sending 404 back.

Comment: You need to point the subdomain to a different IP address then. nginx has no choice but to operate on every request which comes in on the IP that it's bound to.